# Обновление полей модели при изменение значений другого поля

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

в asp.net MVC проекте у модели есть допустим 3 поля. Для простоты и наглядности опишу это как калькулятор пройденного пути. Т.е. есть 3 переменные: `double Time`, `double Velocity`, `double Way`. При задании значений `Time` и `Velocity` поле `Way` должно само подсчитывай и показывать значение. Без нажатий на кнопку. 
 Как это можно сделать? А если нельзя то как это сделать более оптимально и удобно.

Comment: Учитывая простоту вычислений и то, что мы никак это не используем вне этой формулы, то делать можно в UI-слое (контроллер или вообще JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без нажатий на кнопку рекомендовал бы обычный js без участия сервера (тем более если требуются только вычисления)

```js
function calcWay(evt){
 document.getElementById('way').value = +document.getElementById('velocity').value * +document.getElementById('time').value;
}
document.getElementById('time').addEventListener('input', calcWay);
document.getElementById('velocity').addEventListener('input', calcWay);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="time" />
<input type="text" id="velocity" />
<input type="text" id="way" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо полей использовать [свойства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). И либо `Way` является вычисляемым свойством, либо обновление `Time` и `Velocity` вызывают пересчёт значения `Way`.

Comment: скорее всего это поможет, но я протестировать не могу т.к. в свойство которые должно выводиться выбрасывает исключение: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." как её можно исправить? (PS вывожу её @Model.Way, а в get отлавливаю NullReferenceException и если исклчюение возникает должно возвращать -1)